# Pyparsing - parse a subgrammar from a parse action

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a file that consists of a list of "statements", each of which contains a variable length comma-separated list of "columns", where the end of a statement is denoted by a semicolon:

```
head(
    col1,
    col2
);
head2(
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
);
```

I have a working grammar for the complete file, but if there is a syntax error in one of the columns the error message is not very informative - it essentially says the whole statement is bad at the opening paren.

So I'd like to parse each column individually so that errors in that column can be reported more informatively.  The following will parse the whole file (two statements) and print each statement and the column list from parse actions:

```
from pyparsing import Group, Literal, ParseException
from pyparsing import SkipTo, Suppress, commaSeparatedList
from pyparsing import Word, ZeroOrMore, alphas, alphanums

def parse_stmt(strng, loc, toks):
    print("++",toks,"++",loc,"++")

def parse_col(strng, loc, toks):
    # cols = commaSeparatedList(toks)
    print("==",toks,"===",loc,"==")

specs = '$_-'
name = Word(alphas+specs, alphanums+specs)
term = Literal(')') + Literal(';')
init = name
statement = Group(init.setParseAction(parse_stmt) + Suppress(Literal('(')) + \
            SkipTo(term).setParseAction(parse_col) + Suppress(term))
script = ZeroOrMore(statement)

ss = '\
abc(d 45, e, f g h); \
s2("much" "stuff", 34 48); \
'

print(ss)
try:
    print(script.parseString(ss))
except ParseException as err:
    print(" "*(err.column-1) + "^")
    print(err)
```

Resulting in:

```
abc(d 45, e, f g h); s2("much" "stuff", 34 48); 
++ ['abc'] ++ 0 ++
== ['d 45, e, f g h'] === 4 ==
++ ['s2'] ++ 21 ++
== ['"much" "stuff", 34 48'] === 24 ==
[['abc', 'd 45, e, f g h'], ['s2', '"much" "stuff", 34 48']]
```

But as soon as I try to parse the column list by uncommenting `cols = commaSeparatedList(toks)` everything blows up:

```
abc(d 45, e, f g h); s2("much" "stuff", 34 48); 
++ ['abc'] ++ 0 ++
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pt.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(script.parseString(ss))
  File "pyparsing.py", line 1115, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "pyparsing.py", line 989, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "pyparsing.py", line 2732, in parseImpl
    loc, tokens = self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
  File "pyparsing.py", line 989, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "pyparsing.py", line 2624, in parseImpl
    return self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
  File "pyparsing.py", line 989, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "pyparsing.py", line 2378, in parseImpl
    loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "pyparsing.py", line 1015, in _parseNoCache
    tokens = fn( instring, tokensStart, retTokens )
  File "pyparsing.py", line 779, in wrapper
    ret = func(*args[limit[0]:])
TypeError: parse_col() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'strng', 'loc', and 'toks'
```

My problem does not involve multi-threading or recursion, but it does seem to indicate an issue with reentrant calls to pyparsing, perhaps related to [context in pyparsing parse actions besides globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694849/context-in-pyparsing-parse-actions-besides-globals).

Is there an easy way to call pyparsing routines from an action, one that is simpler than the answer to that question?

Answer (score 2):

Changing

```
cols = commaSeparatedList(toks)
```

to

```
cols = commaSeparatedList.parseString(toks[0])
```

nearly seems to fix it, at least for the data example you give. However "much" "stuff" seems to break the csl parser, probably because it expects a comma after the closing " of "much".

Comment: Ahh, thanks for pointing out my stupid syntax error - `cols = commaSeparatedList(toks[0])` has me back on the road at least, and the parseString makes something meaningful out of it.

Comment: don't forget the parseString() method - it's commaSeparatedList.parseString(toks[0]) you want to use